# ngrx/effects didn't dispatch action after http call finished

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have 2 effects set up to load 2 different data chunks simultaneously like this:

```
  @Effect()
  getAssetAllocation$ = this.action$
    .ofType(chart.LOAD_ASSET_ALLOCATION)
    .switchMap(() => this.chartService.getAssetAllocation())
    .map(data => new chart.AssetAllocationLoaded(data));

  @Effect()
  getPerformance$ = this.action$
    .ofType(chart.LOAD_PERFORMANCE)
    .switchMap(() => this.chartService.getPerformance())
    .map(data => new chart.PerformanceLoaded(data));
```

In my component initialization, I dispatched actions to trigger the effects:

```
store.dispatch(new chart.LoadAssetAllocation());
store.dispatch(new chart.LoadPerformance());
```

However only one data loaded action is dispatched when I load the page (I see on the redux dev tool) while in the network tab, both api call are completed successfully. Even though, if I comment out one of the two trigger actions, each of them still works fine on it own. The effects reached the body of the switchMap but not the map operator.

I changed my effects to be `dispatch: fasle` like this and now it works:

```
  @Effect({dispatch: false})
  getAssetAllocation$ = this.action$
    .ofType(chart.LOAD_ASSET_ALLOCATION)
    .switchMap(() => this.chartService.getAssetAllocation())
    .do(data => {
      this.store.dispatch(new chart.AssetAllocationLoaded(data));
    });

  @Effect({dispatch: false})
  getPerformance$ = this.action$
    .ofType(chart.LOAD_PERFORMANCE)
    .switchMap(() => this.chartService.getPerformance())
    .do(data => {
      this.store.dispatch(new chart.PerformanceLoaded(data))
    });
```

So the question is: "My code doesn't work, I have no ideas why. My code works, I have no ideas why."

---

**UPDATE:**
I'm able to make the first code work, thank to @cartant's suggestion.
Here is the case:
The current effect class extends `AfterLoggedInEffect` which is a custom class I created for making one effect run after main app initialed:

```
import { OnRunEffects, EffectNotification, Actions } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import * as Auth from '../auth/actions/auth';

export class AfterLoggedInEffect implements OnRunEffects {
  ngrxOnRunEffects(resolvedEffects$: Observable<EffectNotification>): Observable<EffectNotification> {
    return this.baseAction$.ofType(Auth.LOGIN_SUCCESS, Auth.LOGGGED_IN)
      .exhaustMap(() => resolvedEffects$.take(1));
  }

  constructor(private baseAction$: Actions) {
  }
}
```

The current effect extends it with this in the constructor:

```
constructor(private action$: Actions,
              private chartService: ChartService) {
  super(action$);
}
```

Now I remove the extending and the `super(action$)` and it works. **Is is a DI problem?**

Comment: It's because you have a problem with the DI configuration - which is not included in the question - and the effects are not wired up correctly. The second snippet works because it does not need NgRx to subscribe to your effects.

Comment: @cartant I think you're right. I changed something to my code and it worked. I updated my question accordingly. Thank you!

Comment: @cartant could you please give some more explanation on my updated answer? Thank you so much!

Comment: I can't really comment on it, as I don't know how you are wiring it up. I've always wired up my effects for inject using modules, as described in the docs: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/effects/README.md

Comment: @cartant yes I have this in my module `EffectsModule.forFeature([MyEffects])`